# How to extract all entries in a large dataset from the last week (previous seven days) from dataset with multiple entries on the same day with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, dataset

My aim is to pull every entry (row) in a large dataset from the previous week and filter it to a new dataset in Python. This report will be automated to do this every week, so I can't specify a set of dates to filter to. I think what I'm missing is the logic on how to do this when there are never the same amount of entries for the previous week, and the week sometimes comes in the middle of a new month/year. Here is an excerpt from part of the dataset on how the time looks in the Excel file I'm pulling from (not all dates are 10/14 this is just an example chunk):

[image]

Any help with this is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in an excel file in python with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Then your dates can be defined with `pandas` too:

```
first_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-04-13')
last_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-04-20)
```

and finally, you can select your data based on your conditions:

```
condition1 = data['TIME_OUT']>=first_date
condition2 = data['TIME_OUT']<=last_date
selected_data = data[condition1 & condition2]
```

where `first_date` and `last_date` are the first and last dates you want to include. In this case, your selected data will be based on the two conditions.

Comment: I think I would be ok with the actual filtering but the missing logic for me would be how to calculate the first and last date and compare to the time format in the excel file

Comment: Okay. You have to read in the excel file in python first, and then define a datetime object. You can do both with pandas. I added examples to the answer.